# Gradle 7.4.2 building Scala project returns error "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:compileClasspath'"

Tags: scala, gradle

I am just trying to follow the gradle tutorial to build a scala project https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_scala_applications.html.

However, I am facing the following error when I give the gradle commands "jar", "build" and "run":

```
 Task :app:compileScala FAILED
 
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileScala'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:compileClasspath'.
    Could not resolve org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6.
      Required by:
          project :app
       Could not resolve org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6.
          Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.6/scala-library-2.13.6.pom'.
             Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.6/scala-library-2.13.6.pom'.
                Connection reset
    Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre.
      Required by:
          project :app
       Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre.
          Could not get resource  'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1.1-jre/guava-30.1.1-jre.pom'.
             Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1.1-jre/guava-30.1.1-jre.pom'.
                Connection reset
 
 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Run with --scan to get full insights.
 
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 
 BUILD FAILED in 8s
 1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Does someone know how to solve it? My main goal is to generate a jar file of the project.

Comment: No pun intended, but do you have Scala installed on your system ? It seems it can't find the Scala SDK. You might need to configure your project to add the Scala library. You also seem to require a `com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1` dependency.

Comment: yeah, my terminal is not connected to the Internet, hence I can't download this "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6." packeage, although I do have scala installed on my computer

Comment: If you are on Intellij: you have to add the Scala library jar to your project as a dependency. Go to File > Project Structure > Libraries > and make sure you have that Scala version present there:  `sbt: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6:jar` . If you don't have it, you will need to add it manually.